# How to align rings after rotating

Tags: chemfig

Rings are aligned with each other using LaTeX [chemfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package at their C-1 positions (southwest corners). Rotating one of the rings will cause a misalignment although both rings are still aligned at their C-1 positions (see below). How can I align the two rings at the same level again?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\qquad\chemfig{*5(=-NH-=N-)}\qquad\qquad
\chemfig{*6(=N-=N-=-)}
\par\bigskip
\qquad\chemfig{[:-90]*5(=-\chembelow{N}{H}-=N-)}\qquad\qquad
\chemfig{*6(=N-=N-=-)}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{cp{5mm}c}
\vcenter{\hbox{\chemfig{*5(=-NH-=N-)}}} & &
\vcenter{\hbox{\chemfig{*6(=N-=N-=-)}}}\\[1.2cm]
\vcenter{\hbox{\chemfig{[:-90]*5(=-\chembelow{N}{H}-=N-)}}} & &
\vcenter{\hbox{\chemfig{*6(=N-=N-=-)}}}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]